# backend error ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

When i hit an api : "http://localhost:4040/api/v1/user/getAUser"

I got a Error how to solve this

```
server is running on port 4040
DB connection successful
node:internal/errors:496
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:648:11)    
    at ServerResponse.header (D:\blogAppBackend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (D:\blogAppBackend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (D:\blogAppBackend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:278:15)
    at exports.getAUser (D:\blogAppBackend\controllers\userControllers.js:206:32)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}

Node.js v18.18.2
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

stuck my mind
and i do nothing

some parts of code

added some parts of code

```js
exports.getAUser = async(req,res)=>{
    try {

        // get user id by paramsj or res ke body
        const userId = req.user.id;
        //get a user by id
        const user = await User.findById(userId);
        // return resposne
        res.status(200).json({
            success : true,
            message : "User data Found ",
            user
        })
         
        
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            success : false,
            message : error.message,
        })
    }
}
```

api :"http://localhost:4040/api/v1/user/getAUser"

```
// create token

        const token = jwt.sign({email : user.email,id : user._id,name : user.name},"ramkumarsha256",{
            expiresIn : "30d"
        })

        // remove password from user 
        user.password = undefined;
        user.token = token;

        const options = {
            httpOnly : true
        }
```

Comment: please paste that piece of code

Comment: some parts of code is added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error comes when the server is trying to have more than one requests. Add return statements for all the middlewares that you are using.

```
exports.getAUser = async(req,res)=>{ try {

    // get user id by paramsj or res ke body
    const userId = req.user.id;
    //get a user by id
    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    // return resposne
    return res.status(200).json({
        success : true,
        message : "User data Found ",
        user
    })
     
    
} catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({
        success : false,
        message : error.message,
    })
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is straight forward. You are setting response headers somewhere in your code after the data is sent to the response object.

Comment: this is backend code , not FrontEnd then how can i send headers                                                                           // extracting token from cookie, header,or body
        const token = req.cookies.token ||
        req.body.token ||
        req.headers.authorization.replace("Bearer ","");